# Why is this recursive (?) type permitted in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

I have seen the following definition floating around:

```
getCC :: t -> ContT r m (t, t -> ContT r m b)
getCC x0 = callCC (\c -> let f x = c (x, f) in return (x0, f))
```

But if someone hid the type declaration of `getCC` I would not be able to figure it out.

What is the type of `f`?

Well, `f` is a function that takes an `t` and returns a `Cont r m (t, *something*)`. But *something* must be of the same type as `f`!

So `f :: Cont r m (t, Cont r m (t, Cont r m (t, Cont r m (t, ...)))`.

Why/how does the `ghc` infer that `f :: t -> Cont r m b)`?

Comment: I haven't worked this all out yet, but `f` is let-bound, so it can actually be polymorphic.

Comment: `f` isn't just returning `(x, f)`, it's applying `c` to it first.

Comment: Even a list `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)` is recursive, and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Franky, I did not phrase it well. Thanks for the correction. What I actually meant is that `f` *appears* to be infinitely recursive (it actually isn't). I have on example of infinite recursion that GHC prohibits: `callCC $ \c -> return c`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no recursion in the types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Cont

getCC :: t -> ContT r m (t, t -> ContT r m b)
getCC x0 = callCC (\(c :: (t, t -> ContT r m b) -> ContT r m b) 
                   -> let f :: t -> ContT r m b
                          f x = c (x, f)
                      in return (x0, f))
```

Comment: That's right. The key to understanding this is the type of `c`, which is a consequence of the type of `callCC :: ((a -> ContT r m b) -> ContT r m a) -> ContT r m a`. `c` returns `ContT r m b`, where `b` is independent of `a`. `f x`'s return type is a result of a call t`c`, that means it must have the same type as `c`. This function is really clever!